# Matching animation/frames from different scenes in VSE

Tags: video-sequence-editor, scene

This question is a bit difficult to explain, bear with me :-)

First thing, let's say I have a cube. I'll call this scene A. 
Then duplicate the scene and boolean subtract another mesh from the cube. Call this scene B.
Scene A and B share the same camera flight.
Lets also assume there are other animations going on, like particles flying around, which are also linked. Being synchronous here is essential.

I want to have a crossover from scene A to B. Scene A is covering frames 984-1890, scene B is going from 1870 to 1940 - in their own timelines, that is.

I know basically how to arrange that in the VSE.
Now the problem is, there are a lot of things going on before all that, so the scene frame numbers don't match with the frame numbers in the VSE. It seems hard to adjust the strips in the VSE, including the cross strip, to really match what I have planned.

What I would really like to have is: Set a scene specific marker in Scene A where the transition should start. This should show up in the VSE strip, relative to the specific start of the strip, and other strips can snap to that.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Are you using a "master scene" for your VSE work or do you arrange the strips in one of the scenes A or B?

Comment: I do use a master scene. I can never be sure if one of the subscenes will get longer or shorter, depending on client feedback.